# Cross-referencing between two files in overleaf

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, overleaf, xr, ref

I have two files, `SI.tex` and `main.tex`. There is a subsection in `main.tex` that is labeled `subsec:A`. I want to reference this subsection from `SI.tex`. I'm doing this in overleaf, just in case that makes a difference. I tried using `xr`:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{main}

...

\begin{document}
...
\ref{subsec:A}
...
\end{document}
```

This results in `??` in the output, and a warning in Overleaf saying `LaTeX Warning: Reference 'subsec:protein' on page 3 undefined on input line 123.`

What could be the problem?

**Edit:** I just tried this locally, without using Overleaf, and it gives the following warning, which is perhaps more descriptive:

```
W: /../test.tex:0 No file main.auxLABELS NOT IMPORTED.
```

Comment: Have you written `\usepackage{xr}` in both files?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I have.

Comment: And did you compile both files (at least) twice, in the correct order?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I compile `main.tex` first, and then compile the other `.tex` file. I also tried to do it without using overleaf, see edited post.

Comment: How to get `xr` to work on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/help/213-how-can-i-make-the-xr-package-work-on-overleaf But if you're trying to do this with a PNAS manuscript, the PNAS office has indicated that it's fine to hard-code "Table S1" "Figure S2" etc in the `main.tex`. (Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thanks for your response. I can't see the linked code, however, I get a message saying "This project is password protected."

Comment: That's odd; the link should bring you to https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-using-xr-package-on-overleaf/tzzwtzrkjcpm (that's what https://www.overleaf.com/read/tzzwtzrkjcpm redirects to), and clicking on "Open as Template" should then let you see all the files. (If you don't see a file list after the template has loaded, click on "PROJECT" in the top bar.)

Comment: @LianTzeLim It didn't work but I think it's because I'm compiling the second file by adding `\input{file2.tex}` to the first file. Is there a way to compile and preview another `.tex` file that isn't the main `.tex` file?

Comment: No; at present only one file can be previewed as the "main" file in an Overleaf project at a time; but you _can_ trigger the compilation of another file: that's done via the `latexmkrc` file in the example. If you're still having problems with your Overleaf project, you can email support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, and someone will take a look at it.

Comment: Including xr in both files breaks the references in my overleaf.

Answer (score 2):

Try recompiling your document from scratch in Overleaf. To the right of the "Recompile" button, choose the dropdown menu option "Recompile from scratch". I followed the [guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf) provided by Overleaf for xr package implementation, but to no avail. It wasn't until I recompiled my project from scratch that I noticed a change! I think this should be added to their documentation.